# .htm or .html extension - which one is correct and what is different?

Tags: html, naming-conventions, filenames

When I save a file with an .htm or .html extension, which one is correct and what is different?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.htm vs .html ? What is the difference between them, Which file extension naming is more correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163738/htm-vs-html-what-is-the-difference-between-them-which-file-extension-naming)

Comment: Related question: [What is difference between html and htm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306826/what-is-difference-between-html-and-htm)

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Neither is wrong, it's a matter of preference. Traditionally, MS software uses `htm` by default, and *nix prefers `html`.

As oded pointed out below, the .htm tradition was carried over from win 3.xx, where file extensions were limited to three characters.

Comment: With MS, this is becuase when the web started, windows 3.xx was the platform most people used, and files had an 8.3 constraint, So .html was not possible...

Comment: You can also save your pages as .xhtml if they have xhtml doctypes, and the browsers will even read the page as application/xhtml+xml, but it will not work with internet explorer yet.

Answer (score 26):

Mainly, the number of characters is different.

".htm" smells of Microsoft operating systems where the file system historically limited file name extensions (the part of the file name after the dot) to 3 characters.

".html" smells of Un*x operating systems that did not have this limitation and that were used for all the serious internet work at the time.

Pragmatically, the two are equivalent.

The difference is cultural. ".html" is regarded by some as more correct. The same people tend to look down at Microsoft operating systems and regard ".htm" as unsightly reminder of their limitations.

Comment: As some additional context, the early Microsoft operating systems (prior to and not including Windows 95) had that limitation because the FAT file system that they used also had that limitation. The limitation is commonly called the 8.3 filename limit and it stipulates that filenames could have up to 8 characters prior to the "dot" and 3 characters after. As an aside, its 2017, and except for some particular use cases, we should all be using semantic URLs without an extension : )

Answer (score 14):

When you save the file locally, the difference doesn't matter - your local system will likely treat the two file extensions as interchangeable for loading by your browser. The reason for it is that historically Windows-based systems used 3 letter extensions (`htm`) and Unix-based systems the 4 letters (`html`).

On a server-side, there may be some differences when it comes to serving [default filenames](http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/WWW_FAQ/ext.html):

> The one situation in which there may be a difference between the two extensions is that of a server's default filenames. When a URL that does not specify a filename is requested from a server, such as `http://www.domain.dom/dirname/`, the server returns a file from the requested URL that matches a default filename. Examples of common default filenames include "`index.html`," "`index.htm`," "`default.html`," "`default.htm`," etc. However, an administrator can make the server's default filename anything he/she so desires.
>
> Note that servers are often configured with more then one default filename.

So if you have any level of control over your server's default filenames, then this shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: It really depends on the server setup.

Answer (score 6):

Personally I prefer the .html but as other have said both will work.

**Just make sure you only use one. Never both on the same site!**
link to mypage.html is not the same as link to mypage.htm

Comment: Is there any reason mixing both would be a problem (other than maintainability and tidiness), as long as all links use the same extension as the document they point to?

Answer (score 5):

Also notice that as part of a URI, the file extension doesn't play any role. In fact, it isn't even a file extension, it just looks like one. The type of the resource identified by a URI is *not* encoded in its name. Instead, it is decided by the `Content-Type` HTTP header field. It's completely legitimate (but perhaps a bit stupid) to deliver a bitmap picture as `myimage.html` and conversely, to deliver an HTML page as `index.png`. This is also the reason why it is argued that file extensions shouldn't be part of URIs at all.

Sir Tim Berners-Lee elaborates on this in [Hypertext Style: Cool URIs Don't Change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI).

Comment: I believe the hard association between filename extension and document content type also comes from Windows, right? Mac classic files had metadata attached that dictated which app created them/opened them, if I remember correctly. Not sure about Unix.

Answer (score 2):

They are completely interchangeable.  If I understand the history properly then in the beginning the correct extension was .html but when Windows 95 came along it could only cope with 3 character extensions.

So .html is correct according to some standard or other but in practice it doesn't matter (most of the time...have just done a quick google search and found the following)

There is one area of concern though, most host servers will require your default starting page to be named as "index.html" and not as "index.htm"

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct back in the past file extensions had to be a maximum of 3 characters long.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename_extension

Comment: The 3 character extension limit is only from windows

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer .html, since the name is "Hypertext markup language". .htm was used because certain legacy versions of windows could not have more than 3 characters in the file name extension

Answer (score 1):

I use .htm. Less typing I guess. Or perhaps it's my windows-bias.

Answer (score 0):

Both are working as same,but For the technical and non technical reference please find out here,
http://www.sightspecific.com/~mosh/www_faq/ext.html